# Reducing the size of EBS root volume - Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a technique to **reduce** the size of windows EBS volume in our effort to reduce our running cost?  I have seen some article on doing this for Linux but so far nothing for Windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, **it is not possible to reduce the size of an Amazon EBS volume** because the operating system is responsible for organizing storage on the volume and doesn't like it when bits of the disk disappears.

It is possible to *expand* the size of a disk because the operating system can be told to **expand the size** of a partition without impacting existing data.

The only option is to **create a new disk volume and copy the contents across**. However, this can be tricky if it is a boot volume.

Amazon EBS is charged ~ `$0.10 per GB-month of provisioned storage`, so you need to weigh-up the time it would take to perform the change compared to how much money you are potentially saving.

Comment: Thank you John, this works.  And apologies for not replying earlier.  Quite  newbie submitting and handling replies on SO.  Many thanks!

Just to add that I managed to found a way using fdisk.  But we had to do it cos we were oversized by over 300GB x 2.  Reference here...

https://www.diskpart.com/disk-management/unable-to-shrink-c-drive-0310.html
http://blog.powercram.com/2017/01/shrinking-ebs-windows-boot-volume.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, after much pain, I found a technique that works from [this link](https://www.apptio.com/blog/how-reduce-size-ebs-windows-boot-volume-aws/), which I will format and explain below. It uses a Linux instance to copy over the data from your original volume to a new, smaller volume. I assume you are an advanced AWS user so I won't get into very specific details:

1. Create a snapshot of the volume whose size you want to reduce, so that just in case something goes wrong, your data is not lost. Let's call it volume 1.
2. Launch an AWS Linux instance (I launched a 2019 Linux instance).
3. Attach volume 1 to the Linux instance, as `dev/xvdf`.
4. SSH into the instance.
5. Run `sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel`
6. Run `yum install ntfsprogs`
7. Run `sfdisk -d /dev/xvdf > sfdisk-d.xvdf#`
8. Next we need to find out how much our volume can be shrunk. To do this, run `ntfsresize /dev/xvdf1 --info`. This will tell you something like `You might resize at xyz bytes or 24679 MB (freeing 12489 MB).` Make note of the value you can resize to, which in this case is `24679 MB`.
9. Resize to the recommended size with `ntfsresize -s 24679M /dev/xvdf1`. Replace 24679 with the recommended size you received in the previous step.
10. Create a new volume **in the same availability zone as volume 1** with a size larger than what you shrank volume 1 to in the previous step. For instance, I created a new volume of 30GB. **Note that this will be your new, shrunken volume, so ensure you create one of the size that you want your final volume to be**. Call this volume volume 2.
11. Attach volume 2 to your Linux instance as /dev/xvdg.
12. Copy data from volume 1 to volume 2. Run `dd bs=1M if=/dev/xvdf of=/dev/xvdg count=abc status=progress`, replacing abc with the value you got in step 8 + 1. In my case, this was 24680 (24679 + 1).
13. Run `sfdisk -d /dev/xvdg > sfdisk-d.xvdg`.
14. Run `vi sfdisk-d.xvdg` and update the size to the recommended size * 2048. In the case above, edit it to 24679 * 2048 = 50542592. Before and after shown below: [image]
15. Snapshot the volume (volume 2) and detach it, and at this point you can shut down the linux instance.
16. Stop the original Windows instance (the one you want to reduce the volume size of) if it is running, if not run and stop it. Once it is stopped, detach the root volume, and attach volume 2 **in the same availability zone** as the original as /dev/sda1. If volume 2 is not in the same availability zone, create a new volume from the snapshot in the previous step.
17. You can now create a new AMI from this instance, which should be identical to your original instance, except with a smaller volume.

Hope this helps! If it's possible, it might be easier to just create a new volume instead of shrinking an existing one. I did not have this option.

Comment: We expedited our upgrade and make c:drive as small as possible. Keep log and storage to another volume. Best practice in any event. Thanks for sharing. Some may find it useful.